# Blind man opening the ark/taking out the Torah

Tags: halacha, torah-service, ark-aron-kodesh, handicap-disabled-impair, opening-the-ark

Is there anything problematic in Halacha with a blind man opening up the Ark (Aron Kodesh) and taking out the Torah during the Torah service? Does it depend if one is doing one but not the other?